# SQL Check column present more than once

Tags: sql, db2, unique

Consider a table A. Table A has a column named **INNETTEDTXNID** which is not the Primary key and neither unique and can be null.

I have a select * on table A based on some condition(not related to column INNETTEDTXNID).

For each of the rows fetched above i have to find a value called **isNetted**. The concept of **isNetted** is that if the column **INNETTEDTXNID** of this row is present more than once in the entire table(including this row) then the value of **isNetted** would be true for this row.

I hope my question is clear. Thanks for advance in help.

Comment: The column name could have been a little bit more clearer. Just saying!

Answer (score 1):

Probably no-where near the most efficient but it works.

```
SELECT TableA.INNETTEDTXNID, 
 CASE
 WHEN NetChk.INNETTEDTXNID IS NOT NULL Then 1
 ELSE 0
 END AS isNetted
FROM TABLEA
LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT INNETTEDTXNID 
          FROM TableA
          GROUP BY INNETTEDTXNID
          HAVING COUNT(INNETTEDTXNID) >1) 
NetChk ON TableA.INNETTEDTXNID = NetChk.INNETTEDTXNID
```

Answer (score 1):

This will return the values of any entries that appear more than once.

```
SELECT a.INNETTEDTXNID
FROM TableA as a, TableA as b
WHERE
    not a.id=b.id
    and a.INNETTEDTXNID=b.INNETTEDTXNID
```

if your trying to do this specifically to check if a single number appears more than once you could do something like

```
SELECT COUNT(INNETTEDTXNID)
FROM TableA
WHERE INNETTEDTXNID='value'
```

if it returns one, then its unique, for more than one its not unique.  IF you want it to return something like true or false you could use

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN (
        SELECT COUNT(INNETTEDTXNID)
        FROM TableA
        WHERE INNETTEDTXNID='value'
    )>1 THEN 'True'
    ELSE 'False'
    END
    AS isNetted
```